# Navigate to SASS class instead of CSS from HTML in PhpStorm?

Tags: css, navigation, sass, phpstorm

Is there any way to make JetBrains PhpStortm (v8) to navigate to the SASS file when I Ctrl+cilck on a CSS class/id in the HTML source, insted of the default (to the CSS file class/id) setting? It would be great, and I cant find a soloution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl + Alt + Click`?

Comment: I tried now. Same result. Its navigate to the CSS class. I tried Ctrl+Click / Ctrl+Alt+Click combos in the CSS file to, I hoped maybe from there it will work. It is not. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a half-solution!
If I link the scss file in the head, then I can select the SASS declaration. Yay! :D

```
<link href="/css/sass/main.scss">
```

Thats work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really supported:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6737
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8190

Please star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.

---

Although I have to say that in LESS it's kind of works for simple classes/ids (not made from parts via `&` or multi-level ones): it asks to which declaration to go and offers me 2 files: file.css or file.less.

Comment: Aww.. Thanks for the answer, I didnt find these topics. :/ I hope the JetBrains guys will come out with a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

For **PhpStorm** I solved this with:

1. In the project browser, right click on the .css file that you'd
   like to ignore.
2. Go to "Override file type".
3. Select "Plain text".

Now when you command click a style it will navigate directly to the .scss file and NOT the .css file. The .css file will be read by the browser but ignored by PhpStorm.

[image]
[image]